# No puedo acceder al archivo porque esta siendo usado en otro proceso, como puedo solucionarlo?

Tags: c#, json

podrían echarme una mano con mi problema? Estoy tratando de leer un json despues de crear una carpeta que contiene el archivo, para mostrar el contenido de este en un textBox, el problema esta en que cuando estoy tratando de leer el archivo tras crearlo me arroja el error

```
`private void LecturaJson()
        {
            
            // Leemos el archivo 'Servicio.json' 
            using (StreamReader archivo = File.OpenText(@"C:\\Facturacion EURR_datos\\Servicio.Json"))

            {
                // Leemos los datos del archivo 'Servicio.json' desde el inicio hasta el final 
                string json = archivo.ReadToEnd();

                // Deserializamos el archivo 'Servicio.json' 
                dynamic miarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

                // Recorremos el array de datos del JSON 
                foreach (var item in miarray)
                {
                    // Agregamos el campo nombre del archivo 'Servicio.json' al ComboBox 
                    cb_Servicios.Items.Add(item.Service);

                }

            }
        }`
```

primero tengo dos funciones una para ver si existe la carpeta y si no existe la crea:

```
`private static void FolderExist()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists("C:\\Facturacion EURR_datos"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\Facturacion EURR_datos");
            }
        }`
```

el otro comprueba si el Json existe y si no lo crea

```
`//Creacion de Servicios.Json
        private static void DocumentExist()
        {
            string ruta = @"C:\\Facturacion EURR_datos\\Servicio.Json";

            if (!File.Exists(ruta))
            {
                File.Create(@"C:\\Facturacion EURR_datos\\Servicio.Json");
                
            }

        }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar esto, necesitas asegurarte de cerrar el archivo después de crearlo. El método **File.Create** devuelve un objeto **FileStream** *que debes cerrar adecuadamente.* Aquí te muestro cómo modificar la función **DocumentExist** para evitar este problema:

```
private static void DocumentExist()
{
    string ruta = @"C:\\Facturacion EURR_datos\\Servicio.Json";

    if (!File.Exists(ruta))
    {
        // File.Create devuelve un FileStream que necesitamos cerrar.
        using (var fileStream = File.Create(ruta))
        {
            // No es necesario escribir nada en el archivo ahora,
            // el using asegura que el archivo se cierre cuando termine el bloque.
        }
    }
}
```

Al usar la declaración using, te aseguras de que el FileStream se cierre automáticamente una vez completado el bloque de código, lo que libera el archivo y permite que otros procesos accedan a él. En este caso, cuando LecturaJson intente leer el archivo, no deberías enfrentarte al problema del archivo bloqueado.

Además, asegúrate de que la llamada a DocumentExist y posteriormente a LecturaJson no se estén ejecutando en paralelo de manera que LecturaJson intente leer el archivo antes de que DocumentExist haya terminado de ejecutarse y cerrar el archivo correctamente. Esto lo puedes controlar con el flujo de tu programa, llamando primero a FolderExist, luego a DocumentExist y asegurándote de que se complete antes de intentar leer el archivo con LecturaJson.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad me resulto de muchísima ayuda